# Can the ambiguity in the sign be removed while maintaining capitalization?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

In a recent online [BBC News item](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-40042584) there is a photo of a warning note.

The problem here is that the acronym for Information Technology is also a word. Is there any way to write this without ambiguity without changing the words, or switching to mixed case? Right now it could be interpreted as just bad grammar and that one should wait until the computer itself indicates that it is OK.

Also, I'm wondering, should it be "has" instead of "have"?

[image]

Comment: Well, sticky notes need no grammar. Their life's mission is to convey an idea, and just die away after that.

Comment: A unit such as "the IT team" can be considered a singular unit, or a collection of individuals. Here, it's a group of individuals (any one of whom can give the OK).

Comment: By "without changing the words", are you limiting the rewrite to just changes in punctuation? If so, consider "I.T." instead of "IT".

Comment: On *has/have*, both are arguable, depending on whether you consider the department as a singular entity or a collection of personnel. I prefer *has* in this case because the department should act as a coherent entity when giving the all clear.

Comment: We have several earlier questions on singular/plural agreement.

Comment: "without changing the words or switching to mixed case" So what changes do you consider legal? Punctuation? Font size? Color? Can I make the meaning more clear without changing anything? No.

Comment: In American English, a collective noun like the name of a department is normally considered singular. So, "IT has ..." I understand that this is not true in British English, where it is common to refer to groups as plural, like "The Cambridge team have ..." As @AndrewLeach says, we've discussed this on other questions.

Comment: @Jay thanks. It's an "also wondering". I'm happy to remove it if asked, but I wanted to raise this point in case there was some interaction with the way the question might be answered, since the question speaks to grammatical issues. It turns out that (at)JohnY's answer has no such interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be clear if you include periods to emphasize the abbreviation:

> PLEASE DO NOT TURN YOUR COMPUTER ON UNTIL I.T. HAVE INDICATED YOUR COMPUTER IS OK.

As far as *has* versus *have*, that is a separate question (which most likely has already been asked and answered on this site); but the short answer is: either is correct. From what I've observed, it seems British speakers tend to treat the collective as plural (e.g. *the team have won*) while American speakers tend to treat the collective as singular (e.g. *the team has won*).

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution that I was looking for, thank you!